# MCP23017 - control N-channel mosfets

Tags: mosfet, esp32, mcp23s17

In my current design, I have a few devices connected to 5v and 3.3V rails from an off the shelf ESP32 development board that has an onboard 18650 battery. My problem is if I want to run off battery, and intermittently turn the ESP32 into deep sleep to conserve and optimize battery life, I need to also considering 'killing' power to various devices which the ESP32 communicates with or else they will continue to suck power from the 18650 battery when the ESP32 is in deep sleep mode.

Enter the MCP23017 and N-channel mosfets (thinking MMBF170 for SMD vs 2N7000). My idea is to create a power down function where it eliminates power to any device that does not need it prior to entering deep sleep for a given amount of time.

My question is - would this work? The power to the MCP23017 will remain during deep sleep (the 3.3V rail remains powered), and will my HIGH/LOW state to various I/O on the MCP23017 persist without I2C communication during deep sleep? Also, some devices operate at 3.3V, others 5V. Here is an example schematic below of my approach with low-side switches:

[image: Example schematic]

Comment: What devices are the ones you're wanting to turn off and how are they connected?

Comment: @Finbarr At the moment they are a couple environmental sensors and a small DC fan (would need no more than 8 additional I/O for controlling power). They are either connected to the 5V or 3.3V rail and communicate over serial or I2C to the ESP32.  I do not have any more I/O on my ESP32, so the MCP23017 seemed like a good option for expansion.

Comment: I don't think 3.3 V is enough to reliably enhance a 2N7000.

Comment: @Hearth I was actually going to go with MMBF170 - https://rocelec.widen.net/view/pdf/fonxoqycul/FAIRS29185-1.pdf?t.download=true&u=5oefqw - which has a gate voltage threshold of 2.1V

Comment: @NRav That one's even worse! That's not rated to be driven with less than 10 V. The threshold voltage is not a magic switch point where it's fully off below it and fully on above it, the threshold voltage is where the transistor only *barely* starts to turn on. You need to drive a transistor typically several volts above its threshold voltage to turn it all the way on. Look at the voltages at which Rdson is specified.

Comment: @Hearth thanks for that explanation. What n-channel  mosfet would you recommend here?

Comment: @NRav Depends on other parameters you didn't specify. An SiA440 can deal with very high current loads, the PMZB600UNEL takes up very little space, the DMG2302UK (a Diodes clone of the Si2302) is cheap and reliable, the SiR178 has some truly minuscule on-resistance (but is rather large), and so on. It's a balance between characteristics.

Comment: @Hearth thank you! The DMG2302UK looks promising here, and it has a gate protection diode too. My sensors vary from 1uA to 100 mA of current, and operate at either 3.3V or 5V.